# Listing predicates within a given library module

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Is there a means to list all the predicates that are defined in a given library module for SICStus Prolog?

e.g. if I load the lists module:

```
| ?- use_module(library(lists)).
```

is there another predicate I can run from the prompt to tell me what predicates have just been imported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with SWI-Prolog, but the predicate [`current_predicate/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_predicate/1) is marked as "ISO" so at least give it a try in SICSTUS. Here is what I get:

```
?- use_module(library(lists)).
true.

?- current_predicate(lists:P).
P = max_list/3 ;
P = flatten/2 ;
% and so on
```

Or maybe:

```
?- findall(P, current_predicate(lists:P), Ps).
Ps = [max_list/3, flatten/2, nth1/4, reverse/4, must_be/2, min_member_/3, reverse/2, transpose_pairs/2, ... / ...|...].
```

You should be able to do this in any Prolog that implements `current_predicate/1`.

Comment: @bph If it does you can consider removing the sicstus flag from your question, and replacing it with "iso-prolog"?